# Android blank activity build fail

Tags: android, build

I have just started learning Android development. On my Android Studio 1.2.2, I created an **Blank Activity**. According to my understanding, this empty project should still be able to run on both real android device and emulator.

But, When I run the project, I run into this following error:

[image]

I have checked my Android SDK Manager and the correct (i believe?) SDK build tool is installed.

[image]

Also, the correct version is specified in `build.gardle` file.

[image]

What could be the cause of this problem?

**UPDATE 1**

This is the auto-generated code from the project.

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

The error message suggest that line 7 of my `activity_myactivity_my.xml`

> AGPBI: {"kind":"ERROR","text":"Resource id cannot be an empty string (at \u0027id\u0027 with value \u0027@+id/\u0027).","sourcePath":"C:\Users\Chris Aung\AndroidStudioProjects\MyFirstApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_myactivity_my.xml","position":{"startLine":7,"startColumn":17,"startOffset":487,"endColumn":22,"endOffset":492},"original":""}

And my line 7 of that file looks like this

[image]

Comment: check your resource files.

Comment: @Sheychan I tried rebuilding the project, it didn't work

Comment: try validate and rebuild under file. Also try to rename the folder containing the project. I encountered similar problem when my folder contains "!".

Comment: If you literally haven't changed anything, just try making a new Blank Activity project.  Also make sure that you have API 21 SDK Platform and Google APIs in your SDK Manager.

Comment: @DanielNugent Tried with blank activity too.. no luck

Comment: @ChrisAung It is strange if it's putting an empty ID in there by default, it doesn't do that for me.  Take a look at the answer I just posted, that's the default layout xml that I got for a new Blank Activity project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `android:id`.

I just created a Blank Activity project, and here is the default layout created that gives no errors:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by deleting the line 7 `android:id="@+id/"` from the `activity_myactivity_my.xml`. Now it is running fine.

Answer (score -1):

This can happen when gradle fails to process resources. The resource can be your XML file or might be drawable file. An example, when you have a jpeg file, but you change the extension to PNG, it will generate the same error too. Check your resources folder. And you have red(error) in your activity. Is it code error or because gradle fail to build Resource class (R.java)?

Comment: from your last screenshot i assume that your MyActivity.java is fine